# Is GPT BIOS partition is really needed?

Tags: partitioning, gpt

I have notebook with GPT partition format, EFI, LUKS, LVM, 64bit system and everything works perfectly. I wasn't created GPT BIOS partition. Now I want to test some Ubuntu features on virtual machine, GPT, 32bit system, LUKS, LVM and while installing system grub-install it display message that I dont have GPT BIOS partition.

Question is: in which cases GTP BIOS partition is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two types of specialized boot partitions are common on GPT disks:

- **The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)** is used to store EFI-mode boot loaders. The ESP is a FAT partition on which EFI boot loaders appear as ordinary files, normally with filename extensions of `.efi`. The EFI spec doesn't say what size is appropriate, but most ESPs created by OS installers range between 100MiB and 512MiB. I generally recommend making ESPs at least 550MiB in order to avoid bugs on some (mostly older) EFIs. The ESP has a GPT type code of C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B ("EF00" in `gdisk`, or a "boot flag" set in `parted` or GParted). On MBR disks, it has a type code of 0xEF (set as such in `fdisk`; there's no way to properly identify an MBR ESP in `parted` or GParted).
- **The [BIOS Boot Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition)** holds BIOS-mode GRUB code on GPT disks. There's no equivalent to a BIOS Boot Partition on MBR disks. (Under MBR, GRUB stashes part of itself in an unpartitioned portion of the disk instead.) The BIOS Boot Partition is usually about 1MiB in size and has no filesystem; GRUB stores its code there "raw." It has a GPT type code of 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649, which shows as a type of "EF02" in `gdisk` or as having the "bios_grub flag" set in `parted` or GParted.

The ESP is needed for EFI/UEFI-mode booting and is useless for BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting; and the BIOS Boot Partition is used by GRUB for booting from GPT disks under BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and is useless when booting in EFI/UEFI mode or when using non-GRUB boot loaders such as SYSLINUX or LILO.

Comment: So I don't need BIOS Boot Partition when I'm using GPT and EFI?

Comment: As clearly stated in my answer, no, you don't need a BIOS Boot Partition when booting in EFI/UEFI mode.